# convert powershell script to shell script

Tags: powershell, shell, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

I am completely new to shell script and want to convert powershell script to shell script

eg

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$connectionString,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$user,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$password
  #[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$domain
)
```

Comment: Any particular shell in mind?

Comment: bash shell script

Comment: You'll have to do _a lot_ of work to replicate PowerShell's parameter binder in bash, [plenty of questions related to this already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

Comment: Can you suggest an easier way

Comment: That depends entirely on what the script _does_ and what you're trying to accomplish. Can you share the whole script?

Comment: I am afraid not .. can you tell me how can i convert mandatory paramtors from powershell to bash shell .. how do i parse them?